# warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local with JackOSX?

Tags: ruby, security, audio, jack

Recently, I updated all my gems, and received this message:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure  world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

What is the meaning of this?

I'm learning Ruby, and received this after running my Rails app:

```
$ gem update
```

or:

```
$ rails server
```

I ran:

```
$ brew doctor
```

and got this message:

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

/usr/local/share/man/de
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1 

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jack.pc

Warning: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    ~/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/

Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    freetype
```

But for some reason that I don't know, if I do this, I have problems with [TeXShop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeXShop) (I did this, and it returned to normal when I ran `$ brew link freetype`.)

So I ran:

```
$ brew update
$ brew doctor
```

and the problem persisted.

The jack installed is [jackosx](http://www.jackosx.com/)

Comment: For some reason, many packages will modify the read / write / execute status of directories when they install. This is a terrible practice. Is there any reason you didn't just install with `brew install jack`? I believe it is a similar package to what you installed.

Comment: i found brew recently and jackosx was already installed in system (im musician, not professional programmer) but this message happen to appear recently, maybe when i installed ruby 2.1.1 through rvm. maybe uninstall first or brew do this?

Comment: i found this https://gist.github.com/edwardgeorge/667674

Comment: yeah, jack works, but still receiving message

Comment: Either way, jackosx is the reason this is happening. For whatever reason, it decided it would be a good idea to change the permission set for that directory. As I said before, this is a bad practice. I would suggest uninstalling jackosx, fix all of the errors that are in `brew doctor`, then install it from brew itself.

Comment: Only to remember, is true that create a audio workstation with some linux distribuitions can create security issues through `jackd`? for example, once i tried to make a audio workstation with slackware some years ago, but without success because jack broke every time.